# Незнаю как создать комманду, чтобы ответ был рандомный в сообщении Embed

Tags: discord, discord.py

Помогите хочу создать комманду но незнаю как( тип !аниме
И оно выберает текст из рандомного списка( в сообщении Embed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем список

```
random_list = ['текст1', 'текст2', 'текст3', 'текст4']
```

Для выбора случайного значения воспользуемся модулем `random.choice()`

```
from random import choice
```

Выбираем случайный текст и отправляем сообщение

```
text = choice(random_list)
await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Вот ваше аниме', description = text, colour = discord.Colour.gold()))
```

**Полный код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from random import choice

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

random_list = ['текст1', 'текст2', 'текст3', 'текст4']

@bot.command()
async def аниме(ctx):
    text = choice(random_list)
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Вот ваше аниме', description = text, colour = discord.Colour.gold()))


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Смотри хочу зделать так тип чтобы писало.                 Аниме.                                                                                      Вот ваше аниме для просмотра (аниме).                        Чтобы вот так писалось отдельно

Comment: Дополнил полный код